# How to wait for state update before running a function that is in a useCallback?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

I need to wait for the state to update before running a function that is in a useCallback. How would I handle this?

```
const handleSave = useCallback(async () => {
      try {
        await logIn()
        // here I want to make sure that user profile is updated with a new value before I run createProject()
        if (userprofile) {
        await createProject()
        }
```

Comment: if `userprofile` is a react state like `const [userprofile, setUserProfile] = useState()`, then the local variable `userprofile` will **never** change. Can `logIn` return whatever information you need?

Comment: Thank you for the response! Unfortunately, logIn does not provide us with the information related to userProfile. 

LogIn logs the user in and then the state is updated. We want to run createProject when LogIn finishes AND when the state is updated.

Comment: What code is responsible for setting the state?

Comment: Can you not create a `useEffect` with `userprofile` as a dependency and then put the `if(userprofile){createProject}` inside it. So when the userprofile updates, it will trigger the createProject

Comment: We are using an SDK that returns the state for us. 

Hmm, I don't think that you can use a useEffect within a useCallback

Comment: @Jennifer I think Ryan is referring something similar to [this](https://youtu.be/4UZrsTqkcW4?t=36265)

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi Thank you for the example! I do not think that I can use useEffect in this case because the function should only be called upon an onClick.

Comment: Hey all, thank you for the comments! I was able to resolve this by:

1. Create a local setState [isAttemptingLogin, setIsAttemptingLogin] = useState<boolean>(false)
2. Create a useEffect with userprofile and isAttemptingLogin as dependencies and adding if (isAttemptingLogin and userprofile) {createProject} 
3. When a user clicks on the button to login, setIsAttemptingLogin to true
4. The useEffect will run looking for both userprofile and isAttemptingLogin